# How to find all elements which are minimal within a range without doing several pass(c++)

Tags: c++, containers

We can use the function std::min_element from the algorithm library to get the smallest element within a range.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> v{3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9};
std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
```

The iterator 'it' is pointing to the 2nd element in the vector.

Is it possible to get all minimal elements(here v[1] and v[3]) without iterating several time on the container?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

of course it is possible, but not by using `std::min_element`

something like this:

```
template<typename ITER>
std::vector<ITER> find_all_min(ITER begin, ITER end){
    auto min = *begin;
    std::vector<ITER> ret{ begin };
    for (++begin; begin != end; ++begin) {
        if (*begin < min) {
            min = *begin;
            ret.clear();
            ret.push_back(begin);
        } else if (*begin == min) {
            ret.push_back(begin);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

My example assumes, that `begin < end`.

We are simply iterate over container, find minimal element, remember it's iterator, and put to iterators' vector.

Comment: ok thanks. But there is no way to take advantage of the algo available? They already provided the design to define your own comparator(I understand I can adapt what you wrote, I'm looking for the most 'natural' way)

Comment: @stackoverflower you can determine minimum element, as you did, and then iterate vector again, using find_if. But this is 2 iterations, while my solution is one, as you requested.

Answer (score -3):

The complexity of `std::min_element` is [linear](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/) which means it won't iterate through many times.

Comment: You did not understand the question.